# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when I run my assembly code

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, windows-subsystem-for-linux, att

```
.data
msg: .string "hello,world\n"
len = . - msg
.text
.global _start
_start:
    movl $len, %edx
    movl $msg, %ecx
    movl $1,   %ebx
    movl $4, %eax
    int $0x80

    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

I compiled this code on ubuntu

```
as hello.s -o hello.o
ld hello.o -o hello
```

when I run the program with the command "./hello"
the result showed:Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Any chance this is Ubuntu on Windows using WSL? If so WSL doesn't support 32-bit system calls via `int $0x80`, you have to use `syscall` . More on the 64-bit kernel system  call convention and table of calls is here: https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/

Comment: thanks, I am using WSL...!You are great! my English is very poor ,I don't know how to  express my thanks toyou @Michael Petch

Comment: @Vigiking Note that WSL only supports 64 bit code.  Your code is 32 bit code which will not work.